# How to solve aspect ratio issue while implementing Picture-in-picture feature?

Tags: java, android, xml, picture-in-picture

I am trying to include a PiP(Picture-in-picture) feature in an app. I am encountering the following error :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: enterPictureInPictureMode: Aspect ratio is too extreme (must be between 0.418410 and 2.390000).
```

I would like to know how do to solve this issue. I have tried different techniques by making changes in xml as well as my java file. None have helped my issue.

I am including my java as well as xml code for more clarity :

Java :

```
 Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(videoView.getWidth(), videoView.getHeight());
 pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.setAspectRatio(aspectRatio).build();
 enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build());
```

XML :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.courses.oustchat.VideoPipActivity">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/pipvideoview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Pls. do provide a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

This error happen because videoView.getWidth and .getheight method gives value more than pip mode support as exception saying the aspect ratio you set is more than pip mode support. Let's leave it to android by not setting ratio by yourself

```
pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build();
enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build());
```

or if you want to set custom than do like below but your ratio must be between 0.418410 and 2.390000:

```
Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(192, 108);
pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.setAspectRatio(aspectRatio).build();
enterPictureInPictureMode(pictureInPictureParamsBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Hi, I want to know what the default aspect ratio is when no aspect ratio is set.